Anylogic: perform multiple delays (processing time) on a single agent at the same service agent
I am trying to simulate an air craft engine assembly bay.
What I'm trying to model:

Multiple operations(delays) requiring some time happen on a single agent at any bay (Have chosen service to do the same)
Some of the operations(delay time) require resource to be present

Here's how it would look.
An aircraft engine is comprised of 10 different modules. Every bay (service) assembles these modules and requires certain time(delay time). Certain operations(delay time) require a resource for the operation to start. the resource stays till the complete operation is over.
Adding this for someone who is migrating from plant simulation tecnomatix to Anylogic
I know a bit of plant simulation tecnomatix, Over there the same can be implemented using outin method. Outin method doesn't let the engine exit the part until explicitively told to do so by "@.move(exit)" command.
Not sure if something similar can be done here. Don't know the exact keyword to search for in Anylogic.
Note
1.I'm new to Anylogic and using ple version.
2.While posting this question, used multiple keywords in the title of stack overflow to search if a similar question exists. couldn't find any. Thanks in advance.

Welcome to SOF and Anylogic :) You need to start doing some tutorials first, this is basic process-library stuff with Services and ResourcePools. SOF is not a place for "How to" questions, though, better use LinkedIn. See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community . And do this tutorial: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/job-shop/index.html

also, enough to only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse other SOF users  :)
